# help with json format for batch create prospects with pypardot in Python

Tags: json, python, pardot

I'm interested in creating multiple new prospects from a CSV file with the batch_create method for Prospects objects in the pypardot package in Python. The method calls for the prospect information (email, name, ...) in JSON format. After reading in the csv file I'm using json.dumps() to create the JSON format but I keep on getting an

> error#71: invalid JSON
>   (http://developer.pardot.com/kb/error-codes-messages/#error-code-71).

Here is what my info looks like after json.dumps()

```
{"prospects": [{"first_name": "fname1", "last_name": "lname1", "email": "name1@test.com"},
{"first_name": "fname2", "last_name": "lname2", "email": "name2@test.com"}]}
```

The data type is a string.

Comment: Please try to come up with a more specific question. Asking *"Any suggestions?"* does not add any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Json samples in the [documentation](http://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-3/prospects/#updating-email-list-subscriptions) (api V3) and the error code, your json is incorrectly formated.

```
{
    "prospects": {
        "1234": {
            "first_name": "New first name",
            "last_name": "New last name"
        },
        "some@email.com": {
            "first_name": "New first name",
            "last_name": "New last name"
        },
        "some.other@email.com": {
            "first_name": "New first name",
            "last_name": "New last name"
        }
    }
}
```

if you are using the API V 4, then you need to add the square brackets as you did:

```
{
    "prospects": [
        {"email":"some@email.com","first_name":"First name","last_name":"Last name"},
        {"email":"some@email.com","first_name":"First name","last_name":"Last name"},
        {"email":"some@email.com","first_name":"First name","last_name":"Last name"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: what api version are you using?

Comment: I installed pypardot4 but changed the client.py file to access version 3...

Comment: so, i updated my answer with both api version formattings